# How can superset connect Azure Synapse Data Warehouse(not build-in)?

Tags: apache-superset, azure-synapse-analytics

I'd like to use superset to connect with Azure Synapse Data Warehouse.(Not Azure SQL Server)
I can use the pyodbc python driver to connect it successfully.
But I cannot connect it using superset connection string referred here https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/sql-server

What is the connection string for that?

Below are the connection which I am using.

python odbc driver:

```
import pyodbc

pyodbc.connect()
DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=myserver.sql.azuresynapse.net;PORT=1433;DATABASE=mydb;UID=user;PWD=password
```

superset connection string:

```
mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=DRIVER={ODBC+Driver+18+for+SQL+Server};SERVER=tcp:myserver.sql.azuresynapse.net,1433;DATABASE=mydb;UID=user;PWD=password
```

with error:

> SupersetError(message="(pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]111214;An attempt to complete a transaction has failed. No corresponding transaction found. (111214) (SQLEndTran)')\n(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)", error_type=<SupersetErrorType.GENERIC_DB_ENGINE_ERROR: 'GENERIC_DB_ENGINE_ERROR'>, level=<ErrorLevel.ERROR: 'error'>, extra={'engine_name': 'Azure Synapse', 'issue_codes': [{'code': 1002, 'message': 'Issue 1002 - The database returned an unexpected error.'}]})] [546536][139917057312512